# In Icefaces, submitting form on Enter in IE

Tags: html, jsf, icefaces, icefaces-3

In IE9, when I submit a form (Login form) using Enter, the form is submitted and it navigate to targeted page, but I get this error in IE console:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'nodeName': object is null or undefined
```

and the next page will not respond to any commandLink or button clicks. 
If I submit the form by clicking submit button everything is fine.

I had the same problem with other browsers (chrome, FF , safari) but it was fixed in the recent Icefaces update (3.1)

I use 
    action="#{Login.loginButton_action}"
in the password field to submit

Comment: Report to ICEfaces guys.

Comment: I already did, I want to know if someone found a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Can you please provide link to related ICEfaces bug report.

Comment: @Infragile http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-8478